# How to Zoom in with 1.10 Optifine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

I have 1.10 OptiFine, but when I go to the Controls options in the Menu, it doesn't say Zoom or anything like that. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Support for modded Minecrfat is off topic

Comment: @JimJones No, *tech support* is off-topic. Gameplay is still fine.

Comment: @Frank ok I got it

Comment: I see it under `Miscellaneous` in `Controls` options.

Comment: send a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Under **Controls**, you can switch the key to zoom.

[image: Optifine controls screen]

Just scroll down under **Miscellaneous**.